# How to split an Array into usable data, so it can be counted and manipulated

Tags: php, mysql

I have this query:

```
SELECT carID FROM reservations WHERE startDate < '".$sqlretdate."' AND endDate > '".$sqlcoldate."' OR startDate = '".$sqlcoldate."' OR endDate = '".$sqlretdate."'"
```

Using a loop:

```
while($presentid = mysql_fetch_array($checkreservations)) {
```

This returns an array of data, so for example:

```
echo "<---space-->";
print_r($presentid['carID']);
```

Would display:

```
<---space-->11<---space-->10<---space-->2<---space-->8<---space-->9<---space-->7
```

This is a list of ids, I need to do something with each of them.

I can explode it:

```
print_r(explode(" ", $presentid['carID']));
```

And this would make it print like this:

```
Array ( [0] => 11 ) Array ( [0] => 10 ) Array ( [0] => 2 ) Array ( [0] => 8 ) Array ( [0] => 9 ) Array ( [0] => 7 )
```

How do I totally split each id and store it into a variable, so I can use them to do something else?

In this case each ID is unique to a car, and has a model name associated to it, so I want to use the id to find out which model name is related to it, count the number of that model name in the database, and then check to see how many of the returned ids related to that model, and therefore how many there is left. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: Start by learning about `JOINS` in SQL queries

Comment: It certainly sounds like you can get MySQL to do the hard work for you here.

Comment: Side note, I don't think your query gets you the results you think it does.  FYI, MySQL has `>=` and `<=` operators.  Also, `print_r` is *only* used for debugging, not for normal `echo` operations.

Comment: maybe a mysql with php tutorial might help you

Answer (score 0):

You can't store it into a basic variable without overwriting it, unless you want to reserve very many variables, It's best to go through the loop, store the values into an array, then you can walk trough the array once the while loop is over, unless you can just do something with them right away.

"How do I totally split each id and store it into a variable"

```
while($presentid = mysql_fetch_array($checkreservations))
{
    $carId = $presentid['carID'];
    $array[] = array('id' => $carId );
}
```

So you can parse through the array once It's over.

Comment: `$presentid['carID']` is just one value, it doesn't contain any spaces.  The `explode` is incorrect here.

Comment: I wasn't intending to teach the author how his data are stored, but the values he listed appear to be as you described. So yes.

Answer (score 0):

In your `while` loop, `$presentid` represents each row in the result set.  `$presentid['carID']`  is *not* an array!  It's one `carID` value.  You do *not* need to use `explode` here at all.

```
while($presentid = mysql_fetch_array($checkreservations)) {
    // This *is* each car ID!  Do with it what you want.
    $carID = $presentid['carID'];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$ids = array();
$count = 0;
while($presentid = mysql_fetch_array($checkreservations)) {
    $ids['car_' . $count++] = $presentid['carID'];
}
extract($ids);
```

This will give you independent variables:

```
$car_0 = 11;
$car_1 = 12;
$car_2 = 2;
```

..etc